# Modify the columns of the Sprint Board in team foundation server

Tags: tfs, agile, scrum, backlog

I am using MS Team Foundation Server to implemet Scrum and I would like to see the whole progress and **add some columns in the board** to be more clear and bright

When I go to the public board of all PBIs, I can customize the delivery operation.
I can Add new columns: Committed, Tested, Published etc.

[Public Board PBIs Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mqamw.png)

But the problem is when I try to customize the sprint board, it seems to be untouchable
I couldn’t add any new columns any way, or even edit columns name

[Sprint Board PBIs Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjxsv.png)

Am I wrong trying to do such thing ? should I just leave it and live with that? Is there any alternative way to my PBIs pass in testing and committing process?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Steps:

1. Export work item (e.g. task) through WitAdmin command.
2. Add custom state to workflow section
3. Export ProcessConfiguration process file through WitAdmin command.
4. Add state item in TaskBacklog=>States section. For example:

   `<States>
     <State type="Proposed" value="To Do" />
     <State type="InProgress" value="In Progress" />
     <State type="InProgress" value="Review" />
     <State type="Complete" value="Done" />
   </States>`
5. Import modified work item file and process file to the team project
6. Check the result in web access.

Note: If you are using TFS 2012, please change the version for export process configuration article to 2012. It is different.

If you just need to change the column name, please just modify process configuration file.

Regards

Comment: Thanks so much, I will try it and let you know.
any resources about those ProcessConfiguration  and dealing with xml to edit those configuration?

Comment: Using WITAdmin to export and import process configure file. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh500413.aspx, The xml file could be edited through NotePad.