# How does VSTS Task board column customization works?

Tags: tfs, automation, azure-devops

In TFS 2017 (Web based) task board (for each iteration path), we don't see column customization options to add or remove but after migrating on premise TFS I can see some of the existing iterations having the existing customized column.

Where all the details are saved (configuration portal or TFS DB) and how can we enable option to configure columns for task board?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding custom task board columns in TFS, you can refer to this thread: [Modify the columns of the Sprint Board in team foundation server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38467746/modify-the-columns-of-the-sprint-board-in-team-foundation-server)

Regarding VSTS, as Danko said that the feature is not available.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are asking for the customization of the VSTS Task Board columns, which is still planned as a feature to be done, and not available yet. You could vote for it at the [Visual Studio Uservoice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/3229015-customize-the-columns-on-the-task-board).

Comment: Hi Danko, But how i am able to see existing iterations with the customized columns after upgrading our on-premise TFS  ?

Comment: VSTS and TFS on-premise are different products, having different features and different level of customization is enabled in both of them. Using VSTS you would have to stick to a predefined visualizations, while on your on-premise version you have the ability to customize everything. More information is available here for the Task Board customization in the different versions of the TFS product.

Comment: Thanks for the information :) but seems you were supposed to share link but missed somehow :)

Comment: You are correct, trying to add it again here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/scrum/task-board

Comment: Thanks a lot Danko:)

Comment: You are welcome, if you find my answers useful, you could up vote them :)